# User to user Private Messaging System

Tags: php, mysql

The below link is an image for the user inbox.

[image]

I'm trying to create an inbox for a user that receives messages from other users. The problem I'm having is that when userA sends a message to userB, userB's inbox sees a message from userA. But when userA sends userB another message, userB get two new message of userA. For example:

userB's Inbox:

userA new message
userA new message

I'm trying to avoid two of the same username and to just display one. I've tried grouping by the sender username. It works but then when userA sends userB a message, the new message doesn't display in the inbox. I've been working on this for a while now and can't seem to fin a solution. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my source code for the user inbox.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Inbox</title>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color: silver;
            }
            #ustatus{
                color: green;
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 750px;
            }
            #container{
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 750px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            #container #content{
                margin-top: 20px;
                color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='ustatus'><b><?php echo "<a href='./members.php'>" . $username . "        </a>"; ?></b></div>
        <div id='container'>
            <div id='content'>
                <?php
                $getid = $_GET['id'];
                $getmsgid = $_GET['msgid'];
                require_once("./connect.php");

                /* $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT messages.id, messages.msg_id, messages.sender_id, messages.sender_user, messages.message, messages.open FROM messages INNER JOIN read_messages WHERE messages.receiver_id='".$userid."' AND read_messages.receiver_id='".$userid."'");
                  $read_msg_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT messages.id, messages.msg_id, messages.sender_id, messages.sender_user, messages.message, messages.open FROM messages INNER JOIN read_messages WHERE messages.receiver_id='".$userid."' AND read_messages.receiver_id='".$userid."' GROUP BY messages.sender_id, read_messages.sender_id"); */

                $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (LEAST (sender_id, receiver_id), GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id)) IN (SELECT LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id) x, GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id) y FROM messages GROUP BY x, y) AND '$userid' IN (receiver_id) ORDER BY id DESC")or die(mysqli_error($con));

                $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                if ($numrows > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                        $dbid = $row['id'];
                        $dbmsgid = $row['msg_id'];
                        $dbsenderUser = $row['sender_user'];
                        $dbmessage = $row['message'];
                        $dbfromid = $row['sender_id'];
                        $dbopen = $row['open'];

                        if ($dbopen == 0) {
                            $open = "<div style='background-color: white;'>
                                         <a href='./display_msg.php?msgid=$dbmsgid&id=$dbid'><b>" . $dbsenderUser . "</b></a><span style='margin-left: 200px;'>NEW</span>

                                         <div style='clear: both;'></div>
                                         </div>id:&nbsp;$dbid - open:&nbsp;$dbopen
                                          <hr />";
                        } else {
                            $open = "<div style='background-color: silver;'>
                                         <a href='./display_msg.php?msgid=$dbmsgid&id=$dbid'><b>" . $dbsenderUser . "</b></a>

                                         <div style='clear: both;'></div>
                                         </div>id:&nbsp;$dbid - open:&nbsp;$dbopen
                                         <hr />";
                        }

                        echo $open;
                    }//end of while loop.
                } else
                    echo "YOU DO NOT HAVE ANY MESSAGES AT THE MOMENT.";
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You better put the image after some text to prevent you question to be treated as spam!

Answer (score 0):

try adding to sql query `LIMIT 1`

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (LEAST (sender_id, receiver_id), GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id)) IN (SELECT LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id) x, GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id) y FROM messages GROUP BY x, y) AND '$userid' IN (receiver_id) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")or die(mysqli_error($con) );
```

Comment: I added LIMIT 1. It displays one user (ddrguy) but now it hides the other new message from anotheruser that's under ddrguy.